# How to display custom object as item in ListView in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have entity:

```java
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Message {
    private Text time;
    private Text sender;
    private Text message;

    public Message(Text time, Text sender, Text message) {
        this.time = time;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.message = message;
    }

    private void config() {
        /* Text config goes here */
    }

    public Text getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public Text getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public Text getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message{" +
                "time=" + time +
                ", sender=" + sender +
                ", message=" + message +
                '}';
    }
}
```

How I can override display of item in my `ListView`

```java
    @FXML
    private ListView<Message> messageList;
```

This is image of current result:[image]
I want to see something like 3 `Text` objects in one list item. So I can change their background and look `String text` in them using `getMethods()`. This is what I'm trying to use but I don't know how:

```java
messageList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Message>, ListCell<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Message> call(ListView<Message> param) {
                return /* ??? */;
            }
        });
```

Comment: work through a basic tutorial on how to implement custom cells and apply what you learned ;)

Comment: You need to return a new `ListCell` instance in which you override the `updateItem()` method. In that method, you can set the text or set the graphic as needed. It's not really clear what you want it to look like, so it's hard to give a complete answer (but there are many, many examples of list cell implementations on this site and others). I also recommend you use lambda expressions instead of explicit anonymous inner classes to implement the `Callback`, for better readability.

Comment: It also doesn't really make sense to use UI classes (`Text`) in your *data* class (`Message`). The data class should just have `String` data, and the list cell will create UI components to display them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657299/how-can-i-populate-a-listview-in-javafx-using-custom-objects

Comment: The duplicate (first linked by Sedrick) explains how to create a custom cell with a custom view. If you need something more complex displayed than just some text then build a view and set the graphic of the cell. Other than that, I highly recommend you take James_D's comment to heart and stop using UI classes in you model. The model should know nothing about the view.

Comment: Ty for response and valuable tips!