# JavaFX The items in the listview are not fully displayed, when the item type is textflow

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

I use listview to display some textflow nodes, but when the length of the text in the textflow node is much longer than the length of the listview, these nodes cannot be fully displayed. the jdk version is openjdk 15.0, javafx version is openjfx 15.0.2.

this is a example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ListView<Node> lv = new ListView<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // long text
            TextFlow tf = new TextFlow(new Text("aaaaa...aaaa"));
            lv.getItems().add(tf);
        }
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(lv,600,400));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

and I got:

[image: normal]

At this point, everything is normal.

When I reduce the window width:

[image: abnormal]

it cannot display all items.

At this point, the lower part of the listview cannot be clicked, and the white and gray background of the original listview will not be displayed.
I once tried to put textflow into the stackpane, but still encountered this problem.

I know shortening the width of the textflow can solve this problem, but I want to know how to solve this problem without shortening the width of the textflow.
and I also want to know what caused this problem.

Comment: corrected image descriptions for abnormal and normal views

Comment: The `ListView` has a horizontal scrollbare. That's what's supposed to happen. Other than that you can have a bigger default screen.

Comment: Also, `TextFlow` is a `Node` and should not be passed to the `ListView` in this manner.

Comment: I assume you would prefer the text to wrap if the cell is too small horizontally?

Comment: You should use a [cell factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#cellFactoryProperty()) to customize ListView cells, not add nodes to the ListView item list (as noted by SedJ601).  See: [How can I Populate a ListView in JavaFX using Custom Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657299/how-can-i-populate-a-listview-in-javafx-using-custom-objects/36657553#36657553) (perhaps this question is really a duplicate of that).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In fact, what I want to do is display some text data in the listview, and I have a button outside the listview that uses clicks to control whether the text wraps.
I used CellFactory to generate my display entries. So I can use setText to set the text I want to display for the cell. And I bound the wrapTextProperty of the cell to a controller class variable that determines whether I need to wrap. So I achieved the effect I wanted.