# Why my ListView is not working in my JavaFX program?

Tags: listview, javafx

I have an `Anchorpane` in "HomepPage" `Scene` and in the `Anchorpane` I added a `ListView`. I created this using SceneBuilder. Now I want to take the "space_name"(that is in a textfield) from another scene called "Space-create" and set it in the list view of the "homepage". and this what I'm doing. Method everything is working ok but I can't see the list. what to do?

This is the homepage controller

```
public class HomePageController extends HelloController implements Initializable { 
    
    @FXML 
    private AnchorPane list_anchor = new AnchorPane();
    private ObservableList\<Label\> labelList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML 
    public ImageView profileImg; 
    public ImageView apps;
    @FXML 
    private Pane sidePane; 
    private User currentUser;
    @FXML 
    ImageView closeHomePage;
    @FXML
    private ListView\<Label\> space_list = new ListView\<Label\>(labelList);
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.currentUser = user;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle)
    {
        space_list.setItems(labelList);
    
    }
    
    @FXML
    void create_space() { //mouseEvent at add space
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXML/space_create.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            // Create a new stage for the new scene
            Stage newStage = new Stage();
            newStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            newStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            SpaceCreate spaceCreateController = loader.getController();
            newStage.showAndWait();
    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void addItemToListView(Label newSpace) {
        labelList.add(newSpace);
    }
```

this is the Spacecontroller

```
public class SpaceCreate {
@FXML
private TextField space_name;
@FXML
private Label space_Label=new Label();
@FXML
Pane space_Pane1;
String inputText;

    private void addNewItemToListView() {
        HomePageController homePageController=new HomePageController();
        if (homePageController != null) {
            Label newSpace = new Label();
            newSpace.setText(space_name.getText());
            homePageController.addItemToListView(newSpace);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error: homePageController is null");
        }
    }
    public void create_spaceBtn() {
        addNewItemToListView();
         inputText= space_name.getText();
         if(!inputText.isEmpty()){
             char  firstChar = inputText.charAt(0);
             space_Label.setText(String.valueOf(firstChar));
         }
         else {
             return;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never initialize fields annotated `@FXML`. That annotation explicitly means the field will be initialized by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: You need to call `addItemToListView(...)` on the controller, which is an object created by the `FXMLLoader`. You are calling it on an object you created "by hand", which just happens to be the same class as the actual controller you need. A better way to do this is using a [MVC approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx).

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code. 1. Never use `=` with `@FXML` nodes. 2. Use Java's naming conventions. 3. Don't extend a `Controler`. 4. `\<Label\>` should not be escaped. 5. You should not be trying to add an item to the list in another controller the way you are doing it.

Comment: Don’t put nodes in the item list backing the list view. Use cell value factories to create cell nodes that display non-node data stored in the backing list.  Probably, for your system, a shared `ObservableList<String>` using the MVC approach mentioned earlier is best, and similarly a `ListView<String>` rather than `ListView<Label>`.  If you do that and the default cell visuals for the `ListView<String>` work, then you don't need to apply a [custom cell factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657299/how-can-i-populate-a-listview-in-javafx-using-custom-objects).

Comment: As noted in the comments, there are additional errors (and will likely be further duplicates that describe them in detail) to the issues in the marked duplicates.